# want to close popup and redirect to respective page without any event just after executing the PHP script on controller

Tags: php, javascript

I have my PHP code on controller and I have one popup and after
finishing the functionality on popup I wan to close my popup and wan
 to redirect to respective page. How can I achieve this using PHP. I
tried using following code but its not working

```
$strRedirectUrl = $this->m_strSecureBaseName . 'Apartments/module/application_application_list/action/view_application_list/'; echo '<script type="text/javascript">
     window.opener.location.replace(' . $strRedirectUrl . ');
     window.close;  <script>';
```

Please help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this JS in popup page:

```
window.opener.location.href = "http://some/new/location";
window.close();
```

PHP Code

```
echo"<script language='javascript'>";
echo("window.opener.location.href = '" . $strRedirectUrl . "';");
echo("window.close();");
echo "</script>";
```

**Demo :**

**Page 1** 
file : page_1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('page_2.php');">Open a popup window</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page 2:**
file : page_2.php

```
<?php
$strRedirectUrl = "page_1.php";
echo"<script language='javascript'>";
echo("window.opener.location.href = '" . $strRedirectUrl . "';");
echo("window.close();");
echo "</script>";
?>
```

**New Edited Code**

**PHP Code**

```
if (success condtion) {
      $strRedirectUrl    = "page_1.php";
      echo"<script language='javascript'>";
      echo("window.opener.location.href = '" . $strRedirectUrl . "';");
      echo("window.close();");
      echo "</script>";
}
else
{
echo json_encode(array(
    'status' => 'error',
    'message'=> 'error message'
));
}
```

**Jquery Code**

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "postride.php",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (response) {
            if(response.status === "error") {
                // do something with response.message or whatever other data on error
            } else {
              return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but it still not redirecting it just continueing the php script execution.

Comment: thanks shakti, but stil its not redirecting, m I missing smething ?

Comment: I am replacing particular div with Ajax after click on anchor link, I am executing on function and if its not executing properly I am just refreshing that div with error message and previous data. Now I want to redirect to respective page after successful execution of data. How can I achieve this.
Pleas help me

Comment: can you please check new **New Edited Code**